# Get the checkbox id and append it to textbox with comma separated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code.

I want the id of selected checkbox of my `prescriptionid` div tag only.

I have written the jQuery code but I did not get the correct output. The jquery code is shown below. I want to append the selected checkbox id to my hidden textbox.

```
<div class="form-group" id="prescriptionid">
    <!-- <label for="cid" class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Patient ID</label> -->
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <% for (int i=0 ; i < testpre.size(); i++) { if(testpre.get(i).getTest_prescription_id()<11) { %>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chk<%=testpre.get(i).getTest_prescription_id()%>" id="<%=testpre.get(i).getTest_prescription_id()%>" value="<%=testpre.get(i).getTest_prescription_name() %>">
            <%=testpre.get(i).getTest_prescription_name() %>
                <br>
                <% } else { %>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chk<%=testpre.get(i).getTest_prescription_id() %>" id="<%=testpre.get(i).getTest_prescription_id()%>" value="<%=testpre.get(i).getTest_prescription_name() %>" class="diab">
                    <%=testpre.get(i).getTest_prescription_name() %>
                        <br>
                        <% } %>
                            <% } %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var someObj = {};
    someObj.chkArray = [];
    $("#prescriptionid").click(function () {


        var $this = $(this);
        someObj.chkArray.push($this.attr("id"));
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");
        alert("GRANTED: " + someObj.chkArray);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var someObj = {};
    someObj.chkArray = [];
    $("#prescriptionid input[type=checkbox]").click(function () { // to target the checkbox i added input[type=checkbox]
        someObj.chkArray.push(this.id); // this.id is enought, no need for $(this).attr('id')
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");
        alert("GRANTED: " + someObj.chkArray[0]); // I don't think you need a array, but anyway to show in the alert I added [0]
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is working but how can i append the whole array value to textbox by comma seprated?

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution is to construct the checked array every time from the source

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var someObj = {};
    someObj.chkArray = [];
    var $checks = $('#prescriptionid input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        var ids = $checks.filter(':checked').map(function () {
            returnt this.id
        }).get();
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");
        alert("GRANTED: " + ids);
        someObj.chkArray = ids;
    });
});
```

Comment: @rushangpatel can you share the generated html

Comment: @rushangpatel it is not the generated html, you have provided a template which generates the html...

Comment: from where can i get the generated html?

Comment: @rushangpatel from your browser.. view source

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote i done your requirement. Check the following link page show the demo
>   [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/kaP4Q/3/)

$(document).ready(function () {

```
   $( "#prescriptionid" ).click(function() {
       var someObj="";

    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {

        if(someObj=="")
           someObj =  this.id;
        else
           someObj =  someObj+","+this.id;        
    });
     //alert(someObj);
      $("#sel").val(someObj) ;
});
```

});